# Grey background in navigation bar with searchController added to navigationItem during push

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a table view in navigation controller so that I can push the detail view controller on the stack. It works fine, until I add a search controller to the navigation item, like so:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = Colors.mlLabel
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
definesPresentationContext = true
```

It results in temporary grey background, see below:

[image]

When debugging the view hierarchy, it looks like `UIViewControllerWrapperView's _UIParallaxDimmingView`(selected below) is causing this, as both navigation bar and status bar are transparent.

[image]

How can I fix this?

**Note:** Setting the `animated` property in `pushViewController()` to `false` works, but I'd like to keep the animation.

**Update:** This seems to be issue only on iOS 13. Probably from some recent version even, as I didn't have this issue earlier.

**Update 2:** I've noticed the same issue on multiple places in my app now, and it's not just in combination with `SearchController`. Basically the `_UIParallaxDimmingView` sticks its nose out.

Comment: Can you please share how are u implementing search contrıkker=

Comment: @EmreÖnder please check updated question, nothing fancy. Just `UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)`

Comment: Where do you add the search controller is it in viewDidLaod method or somewhere else?

Comment: @m1sh0 yes, `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: do you need to use transparent navigation bar? you can configure as opaque?

Comment: @gadu I've set `navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`, but it has no effect in this case. So I've just tried adding `navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white`, which does the job, but the status bar is still transparent.

Comment: in the view debugger you can actually tap on the navigation bar and see if the `isTranslucent` worked. if it still shows up as translucent something isn't working... you can try: `UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false` some where early in your app like `appDidFinishLaunching` otherwise try setting `navigationBar.isTranslucent` before its added to view hierarchy, sometimes with apple elements it doesn't let you adjust after its been pushed/presented you have to do it before

Comment: It says `Translucent Off`, I guess it just didn't have the background color which I've set now. Problem is with the status bar.

Comment: Looks like it's problem only since iOS 13.

Comment: @AdamBardon How you are showing "Subscribers" text? As viewcontroller's title?

Comment: @ShebinKoshy yes, in vieWillAppear()

Comment: Tested in Xcode 11, not facing this issue. What i have done is created a view controller with tableView and push another view controller on tableView's didSelectRowAt delegate. The second view controller's viewDidLoad has the provided code.

Comment: I've been working on this app since may, and I don't recall having this issue before. I'm almost sure it's some new, under the hood change.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question look silly, but does this happen also on an acutal device or just in the Simulator? Anyways, as a workaround, I would create an empty VC with the hight of search bar, white BG, and make it the first element of stack.

Comment: Yep, it does happen also on an actual device.

Comment: Did you tried `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true` ?

Comment: @KomalGoyani yes, doesn't seem to be related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally found a solution. One of the problems was that I've set a background color for the navbar like so:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
```

So removing the above line and adding the below line to the view controller **being pushed** fixed it.

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Comment: Ah nice! That second line was also in the code of my updated answer ;) Good to hear you can finally continue :)

Comment: You're my hero!

Answer (score 5):

## Update

Here's the code I use to go from a large title to a small title. These are properties for the large title viewcontroller, or more specific its navigation controller:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationController.topViewController?.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Perhaps the second line above might help you?

As for pushing any view controllers, I see I've overridden the push-function from the navigation controller (as I use the navigation controller for each tab in my tabbar):

```
override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if viewControllers.count >= 1 {
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        viewController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
    super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
}
```

## Previous answer

I saw this a couple of times before in my life and it always had to do something with the background color of the view controller itself. If it's transparent you see this stuff when animating.

But since it's a search controller, it might be the navigation bar. Anyway, since the issue is only since iOS13, I believe the issue can be resolved using this:

```
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear (or whatever color)
```

This new property (UISearchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor) has been added since iOS13, so maybe this will solve it for you? :)

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but no effect. And I always set the background color of a view controller. As it turns out, I've wrongly assumed it's connected directly to SearchController. Looks like this happens when the current VC has large title and the one which is being pushed on the stack has not.

Comment: Ah ok, so you solved it yourself in the end? :) I suggest you post your own answer and accept it for devs in the future that come across this same issue.

Comment: I haven't :/ The current setup I have is what I need, e.g. turning the title from large to small is not something I'd like to compromise on. I'm almost sure I've started to having this issue with some recent XCode version update, definitely not at the beginning(like first XCode 11 beta...)

Comment: I've awarded your answer with the bounty which was about to end so that the reputation is not wasted :) Enjoy!

Comment:  thanks. I also have the same setup, large to small in one of my apps without issues. I’ll check the code and post something later today!

Comment: @AdamBardon I just updated my answer with some code I use to push from a large title to a small title. Perhaps you'll find something in there that helps you :)